# Why would Ammonium Nitrate spontaneously combust/detonate when damp?

Tags: combustion

Why would small amounts (1g or less) of Ammonium Nitrate spontaneously combust/detonate when damp? Possible temperature excursions to +70degC. Unfortunately I cannot give you the context for commercial confidentiality reasons.

I was under the impression it was very stable in small quantities.

Comment: To my knowledge ammonium nitrate only becomes explosive with certain additives. So perhaps you should ensure that your samples are what you think they are. Be safe!

Comment: @BiggChemT Ammonium nitrate is responsible for one of the most famous industrial explosion killing more than 500 people. They though it stable, too. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammonium_nitrate_disasters

Comment: Ammonium nitrate is not, on its own, an explosive,[11] but it readily forms explosive mixtures with varying properties when combined with primary explosives such as azides or with fuels such aluminum powder or fuel oil. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammonium_nitrate)